# How to allow type casting between custom and existing types in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, swift3

I have made a custom Fraction class and an extension for Double values to convert them into such a Fraction. This is my code(simplified):

```
  class Fraction {
        var wholeNumber : Int?
        var numerator : Int
        var denominator : Int

        init(wholeNumber:Int?, numerator:Int, denominator:Int) {
            guard denominator > 0 else { fatalError("Denominator can't be equal to zero or negative") }
            if wholeNumber != nil && numerator < 0 { fatalError("Invalid fraction") }
            self.wholeNumber = wholeNumber
            self.numerator = numerator
            self.denominator = denominator
        }
    }
```

The Double extension:

```
extension Double {
    init(_ fraction: Fraction) {
        self = Double((fraction.wholeNumber ?? 0) * fraction.denominator + fraction.numerator) / Double(fraction.denominator)
    }
}
```

**But what do I have to add to make type casting possible?** With type casting I mean this:

```
let frac = Fraction(wholeNumber: 2, numerator: 1, denominator: 2)
let double = frac as! Double //Gives warning/error: "Cast from 'Fraction' to unrelated type 'Double' always fails"
```

Could you maybe also help me with casting the other way around, so from Double to Fraction? (I already have a Fraction initialiser which takes in a Double value an converts it)

**EDIT**

I know that I can do `Double(frac)`with my initialiser, but that is not what I want to achieve. I would like to do the type casting which you can do between Float and CGFloat for example. I provided the Double extension just to show how I make an Double of a fraction. 
As @JuicyFruit said you can do this casting only when one type is a subclass of the other, **so how do I make the Fraction a subclass of Double so that I can cast a Fraction to a Double?**

Comment: Based on what are you providing in your code snippets, it should be `let double = Double(frac)`

Comment: @AhmadF Yes that works of course, but I would like to also be able to do the casting which you can do between Double and Float for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do `let double = Double(frac)` and check what [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) says about type casting:

> Type casting is a way to check the type of an instance, or to treat
>   that instance as a different superclass or subclass from somewhere
>   else in its own class hierarchy.

`Fraction` is not subclass of `Double` and `Double` can't be subclassed because it is a `struct`. You can't cast `Float` to `Double`: [image: example].

Comment: Please look at my edit, I 'm sorry my question was a little vague

Comment: Could I just make Fraction a class then?

Comment: @Eric you sure you can cast `Float` to `Double`? I added screenshot.

Comment: Indeed you can't I forgot to check, I edited the question again

Comment: @Eric read my answer again :) `Double` can't be subclassed because it is a `struct`

Comment: Yes I understand but I changed it to class, and forgot to update my answer again sorry ;)

Comment: you've changed `Double` to class?)  check this https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/double , `Double` itself is `struct`

Comment: Oww I understand it now, I thought it was a class, so I changed Fraction to a class. But since Double itself isn't a class I will just stick with the  `Double(fraction) `. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

So far as almost any type system is concerned (including Swift's), `Fraction` and `Double` are completely unrelated types. Some languages, like C# or C++ have a feature built in that can define the behavior of conversion between such unrelated types. Arguably, that introduces a lot of smoke and mirrors and can make code hard to follow. Swift favors the more verbose approach:

```
let double = Double(fraction)
```

Comment: Okay, is it a good idea to make Fraction a subclass of Double to make it possible that way?

Comment: @Eric No, for several reasons: **1)** Fraction isn't a Double. That alone is enough of a reason not to. **2)** `Double` is a struct, and structs can't be subclassed (because they're not reference types that can support polymorphism or varying memory footprints). **3)** The explicitness required by the language in this case is intentional. Don't try to circumvent it.